# Show all form errrors using amforms

Tags: validation, plugin-amforms

I'm using [amforms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms) and would like to display all form errors at the top of my page, not just per field. I can't seem to find the answer in the docs. Is this option available?

Comment: Never used the plugin, but looking at the docs, I'd suspect `formHandle.getErrors()` would return a multi-dimensional array with the key being the attribute and the values being an array of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the intended way, but I rigged this up and so far it works well.

```
{% set yankee = craft.amForms.getForm('hotel') %}

{% macro foxtrot(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import foxtrot %}

{# list of form errors #}
{% if hotel is defined %}
    <div class="error-class">
        {% set fields = yankee.getFields() %}
        <h4>Please correct the errors listed below before submitting the form.</h4>
        <ol>
            {% for field in fields %}
                {{ foxtrot(hotel.getErrors(field.handle)) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```